# ImportError for `python-six` package on Arch Linux

Tags: python, pip, archlinux, six, pacman-package-manager

```
>pip                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import six
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
    "distribution.".format(**locals())
ImportError: The 'six' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

I did reinstall with `pacman -S python` as well as `pacman -S python-setuptools`, `pacman -S python-packaging`, and `pacman -S python-six`, nothing helps.

Almost every other [python](/questions/tagged/python) applications follow the same pattern now (such as `qutebrowser` and `buku`.

I think it happened right after I installed `vmware-vcli` manually following the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_VMWare_vCLI) guide on the topic (I know its [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and might be unrelated though).

---

Downgrading `python-setuptools` as suggesting in similar posts by installing the earlier version in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` did not fix the problem.

Comment: There is a mix up. Why pip is trying to use python 3. Have you tried `pip3`

Comment: Now I did. The same error pointing at `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Comment: What are the errors @Chinggis6 ?

Comment: the same error as quoted inside the post above this comment

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`.

However, `pip3.5 install --upgrade pip` worked for me. After this upgrade the error message of pip3 disappeared.